# Odd characters in URL of ASP.Net web site

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I recently moved my web site to a new hosting provider. When I first pointed my browser to the domain name it redirected to the hosting providers page and did not bring up my default.aspx page. When I would type in {mydomain}/default.aspx in to a browser the site came up but had gibberish in the URL - {mydomain}/(S(dw5sf0gbaaipba5aoef3p3n3))/default.aspx

I researched a little and found I had to add the following to the web.config file:

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="default.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

This now works to bring up my site by just pointing the browser to the domain, but I still get the odd characters in the URL. I submitted a support ticket and was told, "We sincerely apologize for the inconvenience regarding this issue. Please the said characters may be located on your config files or your database. Your cooperation is highly appreciated."

It is not anything from a database, I'm sure of that, maybe there is something in the config file that is causing this, or something I need to add to make it stop. I don't know. Below is my web.config, minus connection strings. Does anyon see anything that would be causing this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState
          mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="60" />
    <customErrors  mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx"/>
    <!--mode="Off"-->
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using cookieless authentication. Since it can't use cookies, it must put the session information in the URL. Which is insecure. Microsoft says don't do it.

Change

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="60" />
```

to

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
```

Comment: Ha! I copied that off a Microsoft site regarding ASP.Net sessionstate settings. Thanks, I'll get rid of it.